# Docker application container wont communicate with my MySQL container

Tags: mysql, docker, go, docker-compose

I am using docker compose to put together two containers to help better familiarize myself with docker and I can't seem to figure out why my two containers can't communicate with each other.

My dockerfile for my app is:

```
FROM golang
ADD . /go/src
WORKDIR /go/src

RUN go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
RUN go get github.com/gorilla/mux
RUN go build -o bin/main main.go app.go model.go

ENTRYPOINT /go/src/bin/main

EXPOSE 8080
```

and my docker-compose.yml is

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      - "3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: testrootpassword
      MYSQL_DATABASE: testing
      MYSQL_USER: testuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: testpassword

  api:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    # restart: always
    environment:
      APP_DB_HOST: db:3306
      APP_DB_NAME: testing
      APP_DB_USERNAME: testuser
      APP_DB_PASSWORD: testpassword
volumes:
  db_data:
```

The main app just starts a server on port 8080 and *tries* to establish a connection to SQL. The full implementation is here: https://github.com/bliitzkrieg/go-sql-testing

```
package main

import (
    "os"
)

func main() {
    a := App{}
    a.Initialize(
        os.Getenv("APP_DB_USERNAME"),
        os.Getenv("APP_DB_PASSWORD"),
        os.Getenv("APP_DB_NAME"))

    a.Run(":8080")
}
```

app.go

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type App struct {
    Router *mux.Router
    DB     *sql.DB
}

func (a *App) Initialize(user, password, dbname string) {
    connectionString :=
        fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@/%s", user, password, dbname)

    var err error
    a.DB, err = sql.Open("mysql", connectionString)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    a.ensureTableExists()
    a.Router = mux.NewRouter()
    a.initializeRoutes()
}

func (a *App) ensureTableExists() {
    if _, err := a.DB.Exec(tableCreationQuery); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func (a *App) Run(addr string) {
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", a.Router))
}

func (a *App) initializeRoutes() {
    a.Router.HandleFunc("/", a.sayHello).Methods("GET")
    a.Router.HandleFunc("/products", a.getProducts).Methods("GET")
    a.Router.HandleFunc("/product", a.createProduct).Methods("POST")
    a.Router.HandleFunc("/product/{id:[0-9]+}", a.getProduct).Methods("GET")
    a.Router.HandleFunc("/product/{id:[0-9]+}", a.updateProduct).Methods("PUT")
    a.Router.HandleFunc("/product/{id:[0-9]+}", a.deleteProduct).Methods("DELETE")
}

func (a *App) sayHello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello Luca!")
}

func (a *App) getProduct(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    id, err := strconv.Atoi(vars["id"])
    if err != nil {
        respondWithError(w, http.StatusBadRequest, "Invalid product ID")
        return
    }

    p := product{ID: id}
    if err := p.getProduct(a.DB); err != nil {
        switch err {
        case sql.ErrNoRows:
            respondWithError(w, http.StatusNotFound, "Product not found")
        default:
            respondWithError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        }
        return
    }

    respondWithJSON(w, http.StatusOK, p)
}

func (a *App) getProducts(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    products, err := getProducts(a.DB)
    if err != nil {
        respondWithError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }

    respondWithJSON(w, http.StatusOK, products)
}

func (a *App) createProduct(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var p product
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    if err := decoder.Decode(&p); err != nil {
        respondWithError(w, http.StatusBadRequest, "Invalid request payload")
        return
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()

    if err := p.createProduct(a.DB); err != nil {
        respondWithError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }

    respondWithJSON(w, http.StatusCreated, p)
}

func (a *App) updateProduct(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    id, err := strconv.Atoi(vars["id"])
    if err != nil {
        respondWithError(w, http.StatusBadRequest, "Invalid product ID")
        return
    }

    var p product
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    if err := decoder.Decode(&p); err != nil {
        respondWithError(w, http.StatusBadRequest, "Invalid resquest payload")
        return
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()
    p.ID = id

    if err := p.updateProduct(a.DB); err != nil {
        respondWithError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }

    respondWithJSON(w, http.StatusOK, p)
}

func (a *App) deleteProduct(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    id, err := strconv.Atoi(vars["id"])
    if err != nil {
        respondWithError(w, http.StatusBadRequest, "Invalid Product ID")
        return
    }

    p := product{ID: id}
    if err := p.deleteProduct(a.DB); err != nil {
        respondWithError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }

    respondWithJSON(w, http.StatusOK, map[string]string{"result": "success"})
}

func respondWithError(w http.ResponseWriter, code int, message string) {
    respondWithJSON(w, code, map[string]string{"error": message})
}

func respondWithJSON(w http.ResponseWriter, code int, payload interface{}) {
    response, _ := json.Marshal(payload)

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(code)
    w.Write(response)
}

const tableCreationQuery = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products
(
id SERIAL,
name TEXT NOT NULL,
price NUMERIC(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
CONSTRAINT products_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)`
```

To run the application I am using the docker command `docker-compose up -d --build` which builds the application fine. When I run `docker ps` it shows only my SQL server is up and when I look at the logs of my api container, it shows one line saying `2017/10/01 06:54:14 dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: getsockopt: connection refused`. I ran the application locally with the hard coded connection string and it worked fine. I am not really sure whats going on so hopefully somebody can help me out!

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues in your code. One is the

```
a.Initialize(
    os.Getenv("APP_DB_USERNAME"),
    os.Getenv("APP_DB_PASSWORD"),
    os.Getenv("APP_DB_NAME"))
```

You have not used `APP_DB_HOST` to initialize DB, so you are going to localhost directly.

Second you are connecting to the DB at the start of the program and it takes sometime for the DB to actually get UP. So you need to have some retry and timeout either in your code, or you should wait for the DB to get up and then run the main command.

See https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it a bash script which can be used in container to wait for mysql db to get up and then run the main program

**Edit-1: Updated dockerfile**

Below is a updated dockerfile for your github repo https://github.com/bliitzkrieg/go-sql-testing/

```
FROM golang
ADD . /go/src
WORKDIR /go/src

RUN go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
RUN go get github.com/gorilla/mux
RUN go build -o bin/main main.go app.go model.go
RUN git clone https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it.git

CMD ./wait-for-it/wait-for-it.sh --host=db --port=3306 --timeout=60 -- /go/src/bin/main

EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: He also needs to give the container the name `db`, otherwise the container will not be available with the name `db` on the Docker network. `container_name: db`.

Comment: @maybeg, by default service name is discoverable inside a compose network. So you don't need  `container_name: db` And since his service name is already `db` this is not needed at all. Also better option in such cases is to use network aliases rather then changing container names

Comment: Thank you! That will improve my configurations as well!

Comment: I added the host to the connection string and attempted to use that wait for it library but its still failing. If its not too much to ask could you see my implementation https://github.com/bliitzkrieg/go-sql-testing/commit/125ab7a232ef226098f3509f258a064392f37bf6 and let me know where I am going wrong

Comment: @user2901304, you use `wait-for-it.sh` not during the build but when the container is run. You should remove the `RUN ./wait...` and `ENTRYPOINT ...` and use `CMD ./wait-for-it/wait-for-it.sh --host=db --port=3306 --timeout=60 -- /go/src/bin/main`. I checked and it works fine for me